# PYTHON: Index out of range in get item

Tags: python, indexing, range

I got this error in python and I didn't understand where the index is found in the specified line 756 shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EMMMOIScenario.py", line 22, in <module>
    TheEMMSim.DVThrusterDynObject.ThrusterData[i].MaxThrust=0 #sets the ith thruster (in the square bracket) to zero
  File "/Users/emanalawadhi/Desktop/MBRSCWork/TASKSWork/SSDD/EMX/ADCS/Simulator/EMMArchive/EMMData/EMMModules/../../Basilisk/modules/thruster_dynamics.py", line 756, in __getitem__
    return _thruster_dynamics.ThrusterConfigVector___getitem__(self, *args)
IndexError: index out of range
```

Comment: You'll want to show the relevant portion of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexError means you probably tried to access an item in a list that doesn't exist.
It looks like ThrusterData is a list, and i is the index of the element you want. if ThrusterData has 3 items in it (E.g.: `ThrusterData = ['string 1', 'string 2', string 3']`) and you run `ThrusterData[0]` then you will get `'string 1'` back, but `ThrusterData[3]` will result in an index error because lists are 0 indexed and there is no ThrusterData[3]